# Understanding the calls to the cost function in cv.glm in R's boot package?

Tags: r, cross-validation

Looking at the [cv.glm](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/boot/html/cv.glm.html) function I am trying to understand how its `cost` function parameter is used.

I think I understand that `cost` gets called to calculate the "error" for the test set. But it gets called several more times than I have expected. Take a look at the following code using the data sets mentioned in the [Introduction to Statistical Learning](https://faculty.marshall.usc.edu/gareth-james/ISL/ISLR%20Seventh%20Printing.pdf) book.

```
library(ISLR)
library(boot)
set.seed(1)

nrow(Auto)
# prints: [1] 392 

cost <- function(r, pi) {
  print("Calling into costFunction")
  print(sprintf("r lenght: %s", length(r)))
  # print(r)
  print(sprintf("pi lenght: %s", length(pi)))
  # print(pi)
  return(mean((r - pi)^2))
}

glm.fit <- glm(mpg ~ horsepower, data = Auto)
cv.err <- cv.glm(Auto, glm.fit, cost = cost, K = 2)
cv.err$delta
```

Here I have a `cost` function that still returns the mean squared error with some debug prints.
The number of datapoints in `Auto` data is 392. I am doing K-fold cross validation where K is 2.

Running this prints

```
[1] "Calling into costFunction"
[1] "r lenght: 392"
[1] "pi lenght: 392"
[1] "Calling into costFunction"
[1] "r lenght: 196"
[1] "pi lenght: 196"
[1] "Calling into costFunction"
[1] "r lenght: 392"
[1] "pi lenght: 392"
[1] "Calling into costFunction"
[1] "r lenght: 196"
[1] "pi lenght: 196"
[1] "Calling into costFunction"
[1] "r lenght: 392"
[1] "pi lenght: 392"
```

With K = 2, the test sets would be `392/2 = 196`. So the calls to `cost` with input arguments with 196 entries make sense. There are two such folds and each having half of the original data (=196 rows) as the test set.
But what are the other calls to cost function with 392 long vectors? Total number of data points is 392.

Answer (score 1):

The [source code of cv.glm](https://github.com/cran/boot/blob/5b1e0fea4d1ab1716f2226d673e981d669495b75/R/bootfuns.q#L849-L865) shows the call places for the `cost` function.

The other calls to `cost` are used to calculate the `bias corrected MSE`.
In the [docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/boot/html/cv.glm.html) for cv.glm it mentions as:

> delta
>
> A vector of length two. The first component is the raw
> cross-validation estimate of prediction error. The second component is
> the adjusted cross-validation estimate. The adjustment is designed to
> compensate for the bias introduced by not using leave-one-out
> cross-validation.

Comment: cool. was about to answer the question, but you found it